# How to refresh a long lived token without again login by the user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am trying to use facebook api.i get the short term access token.now i can get longterm fb access_token.its validity will be around 60 days.In google apis there is a refresh token.using that we can get valid access token again and again.there is no such way in facebook so that we  can get a new long term token without user to login again.i am creating a server app which will retrieve a user's post on daily basis and i dont want them to restrict to again login after 60 days .is there method possible.please guideline.

Answer (score 1):

As explained [in the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#refreshtokens), you have to send the user through the login flow to get a new access token. However, as long as you haven't added any new permissions and the user is already logged into Facebook, they won't have to login or grant access to your app again -- they will be immediately redirected back to your app.

Comment: thanks ,if possible plz respond to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22208042/bad-request-status-bad-request-statuscode-400-while-revoking-access-to-app-usin query.

Comment: Please stop begging for attention to your other questions in totally unrelated places, thank you.